# angular: calling a function with parameter using ng-click inside directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

new to angular here :) 
I have a custom directive that have an ng-click in it which calls a function I have defined in a controller (not the directive controller).
This is the html view:

```
<course-pass course-id="bla"/>
```

This is the directive:

```
 scotchApp.directive("coursePass", function($compile) {
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: 'dropdownCtrl',
    replace:'true',
    templateUrl: 'template/coursepass.html',
    scope: {
            courseId: '@courseId',
        }
    }
});
```

This is coursepass.html (the template): 
Important line is the li tag

```
<div class="btn-group courseContainer" dropdown>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle course passedCourse" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled" id="{{courseId}}">
        some name<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a ng-click="markFail({{courseId}})">mark fail</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the function inside the dropdownCtrl controller:

```
$scope.markFail = function(courseId) {
    alert("we do nice things");
    // do some stuff
}
```

The function renders well, and so does {{courseId}} 
But I get this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$parse/syntax?p0=courseId&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=12&p3=markFail(%7B%7BcourseId%7D%7D)&p4=courseId%7D%7D)
    at Error (native)
```

On angular site it says:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'courseId' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

And the ng-click wont trigger the function. 
When I change the temeplte to read something like:

```
<li><a ng-click="markFail(someString)">mark fail</a></li>
```

I can see that the on-click works and calls markFail function, but the parameter passed is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: if it's an ID - shouldn't it be someInteger, not someString? Don't know if that's your issue - but checking.

Comment: Try doing it with `markFail("someString")`. Note the added quotes. This should work. If it does, `markFail(courseId)` should work too. If that doesn't, then `courseId` isnt being set properly somewhere.

Comment: @itamar Everything in javascript is a string

Comment: '<a ng-click='markFail("someString")'>' worked fine (the string was sent in the function.
but <a ng-click='markFail("{{courseId}}")'> didnt work, it sends the string {{courseId}} inside and only render it in the DOM
@itamar yea, right now sending string only for testing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `{{}}` from your parameter -

```
<li><a ng-click="markFail(courseId)">mark fail</a></li>
```

So why wasn't this working for `markFail(someString)`? Because you didn't put quotes around `someString`, thus Angular was trying to resolve `someString` as a variable and concluded that it was undefined. If you instead did `markFail("someString")`, you should be fine.

Comment: First of all, I didn't know that you don't need `{{}}` inside ng-click. That's good to know :) After using `markFail(courseId)` it just sent the string "courseId"  and then I realized that that I didn't initiate `courseId` inside the controller scope. only in the directive. Because my idea at first was to get the id from the html tag `<course-pass course-id="bla"/>` and pass it to the template. The thing is, the rendering worked fine outside the ng-click, for example, in the template,  at `<button>` `{{courseId}}` rendered into "bla" just fine. I guess that the rendering inside ng-click is dif